# How to use G729 of CSipSimple in android

Tags: android, sip, rtp, codec

I have got some source of `G729` of `CSipSimple` from  [here](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple/jni/g729/?r=1079#g729)

Now I want to add it in my android application in order to add support for `G729` audio codec.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you working with `pjsip`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not planing on using pjsip, then, you would need to generate a shared library that you can use from your own project. To do this, I suggest that you create a `jni` folder and add an `Android.mk` file similar to:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

### Glue for pjsip codec ###
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := g729_codec

G729_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../sources

# g729
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(G729_PATH)/include
G729_FILES := $(wildcard $(G729_PATH)/src/*.c)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(G729_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%) 

LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFIND_SYMBOLS    := false
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This is just a modification from `android_toolchain/Android.mk`.
You will find all functions needed to properly manage this g729 implementation in file `sources/include/g729a.h` and a good example about how to use them in file `pj_sources/pj_g729.c`

On the other hand, if you're planing to use pjsip, only thing that you should do is to register CSipSimple's implementation as an external codec (Regis has done almost all the work), this is, adding following lines to your project:

```
status = pjmedia_codec_g729_init(pjsua_var.med_endpt);
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
{   
    PJ_LOG(1,(THIS_FILE, "Error: Failed to init G729 codec"));
}
```

And use `android_toolchain/Android.mk` to build a library that you can link with your solution.

Comment: thanks for such a good answer, the only problem is that my project already have Android.mk in jni folder.So adding a new onr or editing the existing may stop current features. And i'm so new to all this that i can't figure out what i have to do by " if you're planing to use pjsip, only thing that you should do is to register CSipSimple's implementation as an external codec" ?  Do i just hve to use those lines of code, if yes where? and which files to include in my folder ? sorry for too much questions, but really i have no idea about this.

Comment: @I-droid From you previous comment I understand that you don't use `pjsip` at all in your current project and my proposal would work only once you've an already configured and running `pjsip` UA (this would be a subject that would need a new full section/request, or even more). I understand, then, that you are working with a different SIP stack and only want to integrate G729, am I wrong?

Comment: Can u please provide me more details what should i do? if I say that I just want to use PJSIP, then what will be the complete steps that i follow ??

Comment: @I-droid Wow, this is really a huge subject. Maybe you can open a new request and I can answer you there (to avoid messing things in this request)

Comment: as you said here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193956/how-to-use-pjsip-on-android-device-in-order-to-have-g-729-codec-functionality . just help me out from this with complete details.

Comment: @jcm I have built the pjsip. Can you please tell me where should I insert the g729 codec from csip simple and where I have to insert the above code. please help?

Answer (score 0):

Download CSipSimpleCodecG729
From svn checkout http://csipsimple.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ CSipSimple-trunk
and build it as library then plug this library in sipHome project

you have to also write this code in Manifest file

```html
<!--G729 codec -->
  <receiver
            android:name="com.csipsimple.plugins.codecs.ReceiverG729"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="lib_name"
                android:value="libpj_g729_codec.so" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="init_factory"
                android:value="pjmedia_codec_g729_init" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.csipsimple.codecs.action.REGISTER_CODEC" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: you made `.jar` file as library?

Comment: I download codec from your link and made `.jar` file, add them as library, updated Manifest file, but nothing changed. How to add/use codec in application?

Comment: please go to media settings and codec list you can find G729 codec. check the codec and set the priority .....Hope it will work