# error while building pjsip

Tags: android, sip, voip, pjsip

I am getting following error while building `pjsip`as mentioned in this [link](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android)

```
mypc-Mac-mini:android root# /Users/mypc/Documents/FMC/android-ndk-r9b/ndk-build 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-16 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 15   in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
 Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:pjsua: non-system libraries in linker flags:         -lpjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjsip-ua-arm-unknown-linux-    androideabi -lpjsip-        simple-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjsip-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjmedia-codec-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjmedia-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjmedia-videodev-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjmedia-audiodev-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjnath-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjlib-util-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lmilenage-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lsrtp-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lresample-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lgsmcodec-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lspeex-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lilbccodec-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lg7221codec-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpj-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lgcc -lgcc    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
Invoking SWIG...
/usr/local/bin/swig -c++ -o jni/pjsua_wrap.cpp -package org.pjsip.pjsua -outdir src/org/pjsip/pjsua -java jni/pjsua.i
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: pjsua <= pjsua_wrap.cpp
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libpjsua.so
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: /Users/mypc/Documents/pjsip/pjsip-apps/build/output/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/pjsua_app.o: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: /Users/mypc/Documents/pjsip/pjsip-apps/build/output/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/pjsua_app_cli.o: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: /Users/mypc/Documents/pjsip/pjsip-apps/build/output/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/pjsua_app_common.o: No such file or directory
 arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: /Users/mypc/Documents/pjsip/pjsip-apps/build/output/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/pjsua_app_config.o: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: /Users/mypc/Documents/pjsip/pjsip-apps/build/output/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/pjsua_app_legacy.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libpjsua.so] Error 1
mypc-Mac-mini:android root#
```

What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because pjsua-app is not generated by default on the general build (more specifically, `pjsua:` target is not included on `all:` target at pjsip-apps/build/Makefile). To fix this just go to pjsip-apps/build and run:

make pjsua

This would create proper object files at: pjsip-apps/build/output/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/ (needed when building android sample).

Once you've all corresponding object files, you can run ndk-build again at pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/android

Comment: Thanks friend, This worked. But you haven't mentioned this thing in my this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193956/how-to-use-pjsip-on-android-device-in-order-to-have-g-729-codec-functionality question. It doesn't matter now. i have build that `libpjsua.so` library. Now can you just update my old question for configuring `Android.mk` file and how to use it???

Comment: when i goto  pjsip/pjproject/pjsip-apps/build
 and write make pjsua it says "  make: Nothing to be done for `pjsua'. "  
i am also still getting the pjsua_app.o: No such file or directory error + other files too