# Configuration Android.mk in pjSIP library

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip

I was able to successfully compile PJSIP library and integrate it with Android, using a set of NDK and NDK-build command. I have created, so a new project in Eclipse, modeled on the original example. I do not understand yet, however, to end on how to operate the NDK, and therefore I have no idea how to configure Android.mk. Currently in folder 'jni' is Android.mk file of the content:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libpjsua
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(MY_JNI_WRAP) libpjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androidabi.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libpjsua
```

In contrast, the folder 'libs' contains the subfolder 'armeabi', and in it there is a file libpjsua.so

I thought that was enough, however LogCat, is a different opinion:

```
> 01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at com.example.myactivity.PjsuaAppCallback.<init>(PjsuaAppCallback.java:62)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at com.example.myactivity.Breakthrough$MyCallback.<init>(MainActivity.java:87)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at com.example.myactivity.Breakthrough.init_lib(MainActivity.java:205)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at com.example.myactivity.Breakthrough.onCreate(MainActivity.java:131)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3768)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: swig_module_init
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at com.example.myactivity.PjsuaNative.swig_module_init(Native Method)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    at com.example.myactivity.PjsuaNative.<clinit>(PjsuaNative.java:49)
01-18 18:58:03.339: E/AndroidRuntime(31113):    ... 17 more
```

I found this -> [sip - How to use pjsip on android device in order to have G.729 codec functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193956/how-to-use-pjsip-on-android-device-in-order-to-have-g-729-codec-functionality) but despite the user's answers 'jcm' still do not understand how to configure the file .mk

Please help and greet.

Comment: Problem solved. I used simply of the original file Android.mk offered by the library PJSIP.

Comment: hii I am also working on pjsip integration and have generate .a files.Can you please tell me next step to do .I also have followed same link you mentioned but not getting that .

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm afraid that you can not help, because I just ... I do not remember. The only thing you remember is that I used the original file .mk offered by PJSIP. Later, however, and so I resigned from the library, so hence the gaps in my memory. Again, very sorry that I can not help you.